# PyTorch weights not updating after softmax

Tags: pytorch, softmax, weighted-average

I am using `PyTorch` to perform an optimisation problem, which is finding a set of weights `w` such that the weighted average of `x` (`sum(w * x) / sum(w)`) can be used to estimate some variables say `y`.

Below is my `pytorch`'s 'model',

```
dtype = torch.float
device = torch.device('cpu')

class WAvg(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, p):
        super(WAvg, self).__init__()
        self.p = p
        self.q = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.p, 1, device=device, dtype=dtype))
        self.w = nn.functional.softmax(self.q, dim=0)
    def forward(self, x):
        w_avg = nn.functional.linear(x, self.w.T)
        return w_avg
```

Code for training,

```
x_tr = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 4, 1],
    [2, 4, 6], 
    [1, 2, 3], 
    [4, 2, -3], 
    [2, 2, 2] 
])
y_tr = np.array([1, 2.1, 3.9, 2, 1.2, 1.8])

x_tr = torch.from_numpy(x_tr).float()
y_tr = torch.from_numpy(y_tr).float()


wa = WAvg(3)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(wa.parameters(), lr=0.01)

for epoch in range(10):
    # Set running loss
    running_loss_tr = 0.0
    # zero the parameter gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # forward + backward + optimize
    y_pred_tr = wa(x_tr)
    loss_tr = criterion(y_pred_tr, y_tr)
    loss_tr.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    # print statistics
    print(epoch, loss_tr.item())
```

This will get an error

> RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.

The argument `retain_graph=True` was added in `loss_tr.backward()` (as suggested in this [post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/runtimeerror-trying-to-backward-through-the-graph-a-second-time-but-the-buffers-have-already-been-freed-specify-retain-graph-true-when-calling-backward-the-first-time-while-using-custom-loss-function/12360)), but it seems that the parameters `q` or `w` are not updated. I think the problem should be caused by the `softmax` that makes a constraints on the weights so that their sum is one, is there any clue for fixing?

Output:

```
0 1.305460810661316
1 1.305460810661316
2 1.305460810661316
3 1.305460810661316
4 1.305460810661316
5 1.305460810661316
6 1.305460810661316
7 1.305460810661316
8 1.305460810661316
9 1.305460810661316
```

Comment: You're computing `w` during init. It is not a leaf node so won't get gradients and it won't be updated. The only leaf node in your network is `q`, but changing `q` won't have any effect on `w` since you don't recompute `w` during forward. One thing that should work is to move the `self.w =` line to be the first line in `forward`.

Answer (score -1):

```
optimizer = optim.Adam(ma.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

'ma'.parameters()....dont you mean wa?

This is the issue.

It explains why you aren't updating the right parameters and since you aren't zeroing the correct gradients either it indicated that you were back propagating twice through the same graph.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my typo, but the parameters still ain't updated after changing `ma` to `wa`.